# With Powershell v1.0, How do I add the data inside a DataSet to a string?

Tags: powershell-1.0

I am wanting to add the data inside a DataSet object to an existing string.

**Current Code:**

```
$Dataset.Tables[0] | foreach {
              $_
 }
```

***Returns:***
[image]

But when I try to add this data to a string, I get nothing added.

```
$emailBody = "ALERT!: The following errors were found - `n"    
$Dataset.Tables[0] | foreach {

                $emailBody += <I don't know what to put here>

            }
```

How do I take the results inside the DataSet and add them to this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reference Link:*** [How to loop through a dataset in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804133/how-to-loop-through-a-dataset-in-powershell)

In changing the way I structured my question, I found an answer to my problem in a related post that can be accessed with the link above.

**ANSWER:**

```
$emailBody = "ALERT!: The following errors were found - `n" 
foreach ($Row in $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                $emailBody +=  "$($Row[0]) `n"
            }
```

**RESULT:**

It listed the data pulled from the DB and added to the DataSet object to the string.