# PowerShell step in a SQL Agent Job - can't access columns from result set

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a SQL Database inside a PowerShell step in a SQL Agent Job. I can clearly get results back, but can't seem to isolate individual column values.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the problem.

Suppose we have this simple table, with a few records, and a query to retrieve one row from the table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    MyTableID INT NOT NULL,
    MyString VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    MyInt INT NOT null,
    MyDate DATETIME NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
(
    MyTableID,
    MyString,
    MyInt,
    MyDate
)
VALUES
(   1, 'Record Won', 101, '2020/4/1 13:01'),
(   2, 'Record Too', 102, '2020/4/2 14:02'),
(   3, 'Record 333', 103, '2020/4/3 15:03'),
(   4, 'Record For', 104, '2020/4/4 16:04')

SELECT TOP(1) MyString, MyInt, MyDate FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyTableID desc
```

Now suppose that we create a SQL Job with a PowerShell step and try this PS content:

```
$ConnStr = "YourSQLServer;database='YourDatabase';trusted_connection=true;"

$Query = "SELECT TOP(1) MyString, MyInt, MyDate FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyTableID DESC"

$SqlConn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SqlConn.ConnectionString = $ConnStr
$SQLCmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConn
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query
$SqlAd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAd.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$recCount = $SqlAd.Fill($DataSet)
$Data = $DataSet.Tables[0]

Write-Output "Data="$Data

Write-Output $Data.MyString
Write-Output $Data.MyInt
Write-Output $Data.MyDate
```

Here's the logging output:

```
Data=

MyString                                        MyInt MyDate                    
--------                                        ----- ------                    
Record For                                        104 4/4/2020 4:04:00 PM
```

So, as you can see, the complete $Data object is displayed, all three columns.
However, the output of the three individual columns failed to show anything?!
One might assume that they are null, and if I try to add a method call like toString(), I get an error indicating that they are indeed null ("You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.").   I don't understand since I've already demonstrated that I've retrieved data from the DB!

I tried the exact same PS script content in the PowerShell ISE and the varchar & int columns are displayed, but not the date column.   In the PS ISE, if I cast the date to varchar, or add a toString() method call, I get the date column displayed out just fine.   Neither technique helps the PS script in the PowerShell step in my SQL Job.   Any ideas on how to access the values for those columns?

Comment: That's because `$Data` is a DataTable, e.g.: `Get-Member -InputObject $Data | FL`. You need to access its rows and columns just as you would from any other .NET-based language, e.g.: [How to loop through a dataset in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/804713/390122)

Comment: You need to iterate through your dataset, like @AlwaysLearning mentioned

    `foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    { 
      write-host $Row[0]
      write-host $Row[1]
      write-host $Row[2]
    }`

Comment: The foreach suggested by @AussieJoe worked great interactively - I even replaced $Row[0] with $Row.MyString, $Row[1] with $Row.MyInt, and $Row[2] with $Row.MyDate.    But none of that worked from inside the SQL Job Step.   However, both answers referenced iterating through my dataset.   My query inherently only returns a single row, so I don't need to iterate through multiple rows.   But the suggestions did prompt me to replace this:
$Data = $DataSet.Tables[0]
With this:
$Data = $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]
And that appears to be working great.   Thanks for the prompt suggestions!